# Objective-C - Do I need to de-alloc a retained property that isn't used?

Tags: objective-c, properties, release, retain

If I have a custom view controller class that I want to reuse but when used in one instance has a retained property that isn't actually used during the view's lifecycle, do I need to release it in dealloc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's OK to send messages to nil, so you should just release your retain properties in dealloc no matter what.  If the property hasn't been used, it will be nil and sending release to it is effectively a no-op.

Comment: I've seen in some examples online the following code - if (iVar != nil) [iVar release]; where iVar is also a retained property. Is there any reason for the if statement?

Comment: @Glynton: No.  It's just a waste of time.  `nil` is documented to be able to receive messages.  It does nothing except return 0/nil.

Answer (score 2):

You should release any objects that you alloc or retain in dealloc.

If it's referenced in interface builder, you'll also want to release and set to nil in the viewDidUnload() of your view controller as well as releasing in your dealloc.

Comment: It's not just good practice, it's what you're supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call release on a retained property.  The setter method is implemented such that giving it a null value will release it for you.  In your dealloc method just set it to nil:

```
self.someProperty = nil;
```

Comment: There is risk with this approach;  if something is still observing `someProperty`, it'll get a change notification during the object's `dealloc` where the state is pretty much guaranteed to be undefined.

Comment: Also if someProperty is overridden in a subclass.